# Rでcsvデータを読み込もうとすると、エラーが発生します。どう解決したらよいでしょうか。

Tags: r, csv

```
data<-read.csv("try.csv",header=T)
make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE)
```

でエラー: 'ｻno' に不正なマルチバイト文字があります
と表示されます。文字のエンコーディングのために、

```
data<-read.csv("try.csv",header=T,fileEncoding="utf-8")
```

とした場合もエラーが発生します。どのように解決したらよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

CSVファイルを、テキストエディタなどで明示的にUTF-8に変換するか、あるいはお使いの環境がMacOSの場合は fileEncoding="CP932" を指定してあげれば良いかと思います。